# Javascript Dojo / Javascript - How to replace link inside iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, dojo

I currently use the following dojo script on my site to replace parts of all links containing the text 'local-store' with the text 'bacon'. This is currently working but I want to now put it in an iframe. I've put both the script and the link inside the iframe but I am still only getting the 'local-store' text appearing in the link.

```
<iframe>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head></head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
require(["dojo/ready", "dojo/query", "dojo/topic", "dojo/domReady!"], function(ready, query, topic, analytics){
ready(function(){
dojo.query('a[href*="local-store"]').forEach(function(link){
var href = link.href;
href = href.replace("local-store", "bacon");
link.setAttribute('href', href); 
  });
});
});
</script>

<div>
<a href="http://domain.com/local-store/category" target="_parent">test link</a>
</div>

</body>
</iframe>
```

Any ideas why it's not working?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the context is of the root document, try to change it or use `withDoc`:

```
require(["dojo/dom", "dojo/_base/window"], function(dom, win) {
    var iframe = dom.byId('iframe').contentWindow;
    win.setContext(iframe.window, iframe.window.document);
    /* your query here */

    /* ------------------ */
    /*   Alternatively    */
    /* ------------------ */

    var iframeDoc = dom.byId("someFrameId").contentWindow.document;
    win.withDoc(iframeDoc, function(){
        /* your query here */
    }, this));
});
```

Comment: I can't get this to work, but it could just be due to my limited understanding of dojo :/ Thanks